# Require JSON Field with JAXB

Tags: xml, json, jaxb, annotations, jersey

I have the following.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeObject {

    private String requiredField;

    @XmlElement(name="address", required=true)
    public String getRequiredField() {
        return requiredField;
    }

    public void setRequiredField(String requiredField) {
        this.requiredField = requiredField;
    }    

}
```

However, when the corresponding Jersey resource consumes the JSON necessary to make this object it successfully creates the object, with or without the field that is annotated as required.

Using Jersey and JAXB, or directly related technologies, is there a way to ensure that a value for requiredField is present in the consumed JSON? What's missing from the example above?

Example:

What I would like is it to reject a call such as the following, as the JSON body does not contain a value for requiredField.

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'content-type:application/json' -d '{}' http://some/uri
```

Rather I would want something like this to work.

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'content-type:application/json' -d '{"requiredField":"Hello, world!"}' http://some/uri
```

Comment: If you are looking for null values to be output with a null value instead of as the an absent node the you may find the following useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

Comment: I added an example to be more specific.

Comment: Marc M., did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @FagnerBrack I don't believe I did. I think I just created a validation method in my utils package and ran it at the resource level.

Not as seamless as something declarative like annotations, but it's what the resource level is for.

Comment: I am sorry for the noobish, but what you mean by "resource level"? Did you mean just calling the method without using any built-in feature?

Comment: @FagnerBrack Sorry, that was by bad using was using a lot of buzz words. The resource level is the level that handles the calls and insures the JSON or XML get validated and turned into proper objects. Generally speaking, there is a resources level, service level- deals with business logic of the application, and a DAO level - deals with persistence.

Comment: Ok now I got it, I was just not familiarized with the "resource" level. It seems this is just a pattern you use to determine where the classes annotated with the `@Path` will be located. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default value to your field.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeObject {

    private String requiredField = "Hello world!"; 

    //...  
}
```

now if you don't set new value to this field at runtime, then in JSON you will see  `"Hello world!"` string

Comment: Not exactly what I need. I need the user to provide a value for that field, not have the field set to some default value if none is provided. Thanks though, this is certainly an interesting alternative.